# Как обновить данные в DataGridView при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Здравствуйте! Используется компонент DataGridView для вывод данных из таблицы в проекте. Добавлен через Visual Studio компоненту dataGridView1.

Visual Studio автоматически добавила в onload формы: this.visitorsTableAdapter.Fill(this.mainDatabaseDataSet2.visitors);

Я добавляю строки в таблицу. И хочу что бы по кнопке обновились данные в dataGridView1. Как это можно реализовать?

Если я повторно вызываю этот метод для обновления - данные подгружаются старые.

Comment: _добавляю строки в таблицу_ - что подразумевается под таблицей: `DataTable` или непосредственно таблица в БД?

Comment: sql mdf файл. В таблицу которого я делаю операцию insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как обновить легко и просто так и не нашёл. Поэтому пришлось привязывать данные ручками и обновлять их так же. Код с просторов интернетов:

```
private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

private void GetData(string selectCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            String connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\repos\\Tir\\Tir\\mainDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка запроса");
        }
    }

private void showVisitors_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        GetData("select id AS ID, name AS 'Имя', lastname AS 'Фамилия', patronymic AS 'Отчество', pasport_serial AS 'Серия паспорта', pasport_number AS 'Номер паспорта', birthday AS 'Д.Р.' from visitors");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю универсальное решение через ENTITY, c перегрузкой контекста через BindingList:

после всех CRUD операций

```
      await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                this.Invoke(new InvokeDelegate(
                    () =>
                    {
                        var datas = new BindingList<object>();
                        db.Players.Load();
                        foreach (var item in db.Players.Local.ToBindingList())
                        {
                            datas.Add(item);
                        }
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = datas;
                        dataGridView1.Refresh();
                    }
                    ));
            });
```